Flow is behaving differently when run as scheduled versus manually
Context
I have a custom object (Technology) that represents a bucket of Assets. The Assets have a lookup to the Technology. I have a number of DLRS fields in the Technology that represent different statistics about the Assets in the particular Technology. For example, there is a DLRS field for % of US Assets. These DLRS fields are set to calculate in RealTime, but I have previously had them set to calculate on a schedule, and still encountered the below issue. Regardless of the calculation setting, the actual DLRS fields have data populated in them every time I check.
I also have a custom object (Tech Blend) meant to capture the statistical information about the Technology on a regular (quarterly) basis. This is achieved via a scheduled flow that loops over all of the Technology records and creates a record collection of Tech Blend records via simple field assignment. It's a whole bunch of this kind of thing: Tech Blend -> Field = Technology -> DLRS Field
Issue
This works great when I click "Debug" on the flow. I get a Tech Blend record for each Technology, and all of the fields in the Tech Blend record match the Technology. However, it doesn't work when I let the flow execute as scheduled. I then get a Tech Blend record with all of the DLRS fields left blank. All other assignments work as expected, but the DLRS fields are blanked out. There is no error, the interview doesn't fail, and there is no other indication of a problem that I can find.
Remediation Steps
As mentioned above, I've tried adjusting the DLRS calculation method, but that didn't seem to change anything.
I've pored through the logic of the flow itself to see if there was anything that could explain this behavior, but it seems to be correct, especially since it's working right when manually executed.
I think there's some technical incompatibility going on between the DLRS system and the scheduled flow, but I'm not sure what it is and how to avoid it.
